# calling glDrawElements causes access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, access-violation

Im currently trying to figure out how VBO stuff is working which results in horrible problems sadly : /

im loading the data from an .obj file (see: http://pastebin.com/B8uibDvV for the .obj file)
and (trying to) put it into a VBO

my code to bind the data looks like this:

```
//Generate Buffers
glGenBuffers(1, &this->glVerticesBufferID);
glGenBuffers(1, &this->glIndexBufferID);

//bind the buffers to set the data
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glVerticesBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->verticesList.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glIndexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indexList.size() * sizeof(GLshort), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, this->verticesList.size(), this->verticesList.data()); 
glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, this->indexList.size(), this->indexList.data()); 

//Clear binds 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

at the end im rendering everything with this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glVerticesBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glIndexBufferID);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->indexList.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this->indexList.data());
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

and at the end i get the access violation message in the output of VisualStudio 2010

0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0147fbd8.

So my question is
how to fix this? (or how to do it right if im that wrong)

---------------EDIT 1---------------

http://pastebin.com/DEbZH9iy

**Bind data**

```
 glGenBuffers(1, &this->glVerticesBufferID);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glVerticesBufferID);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (this->verticesList.size() + this->textureCoordList.size() + this->normalsList.size()) * sizeof(GLfloat), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
 glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                0,
                this->verticesList.size() * sizeof(GLfloat),
                this->verticesList.data()
               );
 glBufferSubData(
                GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                this->verticesList.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), 
                this->normalsList.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), 
                this->normalsList.data()
               );
 glBufferSubData(
                GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                (this->verticesList.size() + this->normalsList.size()) * sizeof(GLfloat), 
                this->textureCoordList.size() * sizeof(GLfloat),
                this->textureCoordList.data()
               );
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

 glGenBuffers(1, &this->glIndexBufferID);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glIndexBufferID);
 glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indexList.size() * sizeof(GLushort), this->indexList.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);



 pub_glVerticesBufferID = glVerticesBufferID;
 pub_glIndexBufferID = glIndexBufferID;
```

**Render part:**

```
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glVerticesBufferID);
 glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
 glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(this->verticesList.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)));
 glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)((this->normalsList.size() + this->verticesList.size()) * sizeof(GLfloat)));
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

 glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->glIndexBufferID);
 glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't initialize the entry points for functionality introduced after OpenGL-1.1. In Windows only the OpenGL-1.1 entry points are specified, everything beyond must be initialized at runtime. Otherwise you get an access violation. Have a look at GLEW  for a convenient way to do that tedious task with just 3 lines of code.

That being said, your code still got mistakes:

You need to tell OpenGL where where from the buffer exactly it shall take it's elements. This done by calling the `gl…Pointer` functions with the data elements being a byte offset into the buffer. Your code misses that. Also `glDrawElements` no longer expects are pointer put an offset as well.

But with buffer objects being bound this shouldn't cause a segfault/access violation.

Comment: you mean `glVertexPointer`? I already used the function in my code but removed it after many tries in hope that it could be the problem : /

Comment: @X39: Well, yes you must call it, how else is OpenGL supposed to know where to get the data from? However it should not segfault if a VBO is bound (without a VBO bound it will do so, however). Anyway, your call to glDrawElements is wrong, because a VBO is bound, and with that you don't give a pointer, but an offset into the element array VBO being bound.

Comment: Ok now im just only confused ... i read on many pages that i just need to leave the last arg empty to get it work : /  so how to get which offset ? If you could specify that it would be realy helpfull ( and also could save me some time in searching to get it )

Comment: @X39: "Empty" and 0/NULL are very different things. I made a small minimal VBO example I hereby refer you to: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalvbo/minimalvbo.c I suggest you carefully read its code, try to understand what it does and if there are any questions just get in touch with me.

Comment: thanks for that
i will check that when im back at home (it was that what i ment when i said empty : / sometimes im just not carefully enough with those words)

Comment: i read it and the access violation is gone but now nothing is rendered : /
i updated the code part again but i got no clue where the problem is
if you could help me out another time it would be perfect (if not its also ok)

Comment: @X39: Well, if nothing gets visibly drawn, there can be many reasons. A wrong projection, things are out of view, etc. etc. Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: https://github.com/X39/HorribleOpenGLTestApplication
this is the entire code (but the used libaries)
its not well organized currently and many things need a change so dont blame me for that ^^
the main lays at startPoint.cpp after that the rendering starts in the RenderManager.cpp inside of it i load the model

Comment: @X39: Two things I noticed immediately: In `RenderManager::draw` you're messing around on a matrix without making sure it's the right one. And you've got the typical newbie mistake of trying to "initialize" OpenGL. Almost everything, except the enabling of the texcoord array actually belongs into the drawing code. And not at the beginning of that, but closely to the parts that actually use that state.

Comment: so now i threw out the init code part and changed it according to your points and made sure that im inside of the gl_modelview matrix
but that is not helping much with my problem sadly : /
well but anyway the issue which covered this post was answered so i gave you the tick ^^